# Here's another... A bit obvious maybe but more poetic than most of my riddles I think

Tags: riddle, rhyme, poetry

Between you and your feelings, Or perhaps you and your grudges,

I lie upon large puddles, and ward off constant nudges,

In my depths many appear, look out across the moors,

While from atop a shadow crouches tinkering with lures,

My yard is proudly flat compared to roaming hills around,

Orbs rising in the rain, with their charges not aground.

What am I?

Comment: Someone just wouldn't know good poetry if it hit them.  Not that I'm bitter! :P

Comment: "A dope like that wouldn't know subtlety if it bit him on the ass!"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you a

> harbor

Between you and your feelings, Or perhaps you and your grudges,

> People often harbor ill will or their feelings towards others
>  OP: Yep.  Maybe you harbour feelings and maybe you harbour grudges

I lie upon large puddles, and ward off constant nudges,

> Harbors are located in large bodies of water and protect the boats from larger waves
>  OP: spot on

In my depths many appear, look out across the moors,

> Lots of boats in a harbor, moors are the ties between the harbor and boat
>  OP: and "Many a pier" in a harbor

While from atop a shadow crouches tinkering with lures,

> Sailors tying down their ships to the harbor
>  OP: People fishing from the harbour, literal lures

My yard is proudly flat compared to roaming hills around,

> The docks/piers of a harbor are level, while the water is uneven
>  OP: The water in the harbour is still and flat compared to choppy surrounding waters

Orbs rising in the rain, with their charges not aground.

> Boats rising with the water levels, as they float
>  OP: Buoys specifically

Comment: You got it Pat.  +1

Comment: Edited with some extra explanations for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

For a more literal answer, are you a:

> fishing bobber?

Between you and your feelings, Or perhaps you and your grudges

> People often go fishing to escape their troubles and relax

I lie upon large puddles, and ward off constant nudges,

> Bobbers are buoyant on the water, returning to that spot despite pulls and tugs

In my depths many appear, look out across the moors,

> Bobbers make fish appear below it in the water

While from atop a shadow crouches tinkering with lures,

> This describes the fisherman

My yard is proudly flat compared to roaming hills around,

> The bobber rests in calm waters

Orbs rising in the rain, with their charges not aground.

> The orb-shaped bobber bobs and splashes when a fish is hooked, but not yet landed

Comment: Nope.  I'm not a fishing float.  Might be a few in my yard though.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you are a

> cloud.

**Explanation:**

Between you and your feelings, Or perhaps you and your grudges,

> I was thinking "distance" or "space", as in "put some distance between you and your feelings", but I couldn't make it work. Can't make sense of this one.

I lie upon large puddles, and ward off constant nudges,

> Clouds, in the form of fog, can lie above ponds, lakes, etc. "Ward off nudges" might refer to the fact that in this form clouds do not bump into one another.

In my depths many appear, look out across the moors,

> In the sky can be found many clouds. To convince yourself, look across a field.

While from atop a shadow crouches tinkering with lures,

> A reference to a dark storm cloud, perhaps. "Lures" may refer to the fact that the cloud attracts positively charged particles from below (see below).

My yard is proudly flat compared to roaming hills around,

> The sky is "flat" compared to the geography below.

Orbs rising in the rain, with their charges not aground.

> During thunderstorms, positively charged particles rise and travel with the moving storm.

Comment: Nice thought but I'm not a cloud.  Some good explanations though. +1

Comment: My first thought was fog. Cloud is pretty close. :)

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you're not ...

> **A bubble.**

Between you and your feelings, Or perhaps you and your grudges,

> People can figuratively live in a bubble, blocking out things they don't want to deal with.  Or perhaps keeping themselves isolated from the people they have grudges against.

I lie upon large puddles, and ward off constant nudges,

> Puddles often have bubbles.
>  Things inside a bubble are cushioned from bumps from outside.

In my depths many appear, look out across the moors,

> Not sure here.  It seems like we shifted focus to a marsh ("moors") somehow, which has "many" within its depths - many bubbles (marsh gas) perhaps.  Or maybe, many fish ...

While from atop a shadow crouches tinkering with lures,

> ... as we see a fisher next, above the surface of the wetlands.

My yard is proudly flat compared to roaming hills around,

> Whether we're a bubble or a marsh, either way the "yard" is flat as it's a liquid surface

Orbs rising in the rain, with their charges not aground.

> Bubbles of swamp gas again

Comment: Sorry.  Not a bubble.  +1 for some good explanations